# Correct Freeing double-linked nodes in C language

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm pretty new to C world and I don't know how is the correct way to delete this data structure avoiding memory leaks and segmentation faults.

The data structure is this:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int id;
    struct Node *parent;   /* node's parent */
    struct Node *suffix_node;
    int first_char_index;
    int last_char_index;
    bool is_leaf;
    struct Node **children;  /* node's children */
    int children_size;         /* size of children structure */
    int children_count;         /* # of children */
    int depth;
}Node;

typedef struct SuffixTree {
    Node *root;
    int nodes_count;
    char *string;
}SuffixTree;
```

What I would do is, from a pointer to SuffixTree structure, freeing entirely tree.

I have tried to do this:

```
void deleteSubTree(Node *nd)
{
    if (nd->is_leaf)
    {
        free(nd->children);
        free(nd);
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for(;i < nd->children_count; ++i)
    {
        deleteSubTree(nd->children[i]);
    }
    free(nd->children);
    free(nd);
    return;
}

void deleteSuffixTree(SuffixTree *st)
{
    deleteSubTree(st->root);
    free(st);
}
```

But it is not correct.

EDIT:

This is main:

```
int main()
{   char *str = "BOOK\0";
    SuffixTree *st = createSuffixTree(str);
    deleteSuffixTree(st);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is how I allocate tree and nodes:

```
Node* createNode(){
    Node *stn = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    stn->id = node_id++;
    stn->parent = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    stn->suffix_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    stn->first_char_index = -1;
    stn->last_char_index = -1;
    stn->children_size = NODE_BASE_DEGREE;
    stn->children_count = 0;
    stn->children = (Node**)malloc(stn->children_size*sizeof(Node*));
    stn->is_leaf = true;
    stn->depth = 1;
    return stn;
}

SuffixTree* createSuffixTree(char *str)
{
    SuffixTree *st = (SuffixTree*)malloc(sizeof(SuffixTree));
    st->root = createNode();
    st->root->parent = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    st->root->parent->id = -1;
    st->nodes_count = 1;
    st->string = str;

    makeTreeWithUkkonen(st);

    return st;
}
```

makeTreeWithUkkonen is correct, I can display correct tree after createSuffixTree() call.

Comment: and how do you allocate the memory for the tree? You have to free what you have allocated, that's the rule!

Comment: `st->root->parent = NULL;
    st->root->parent->id = -1;` ... Does not look correct.

Comment: In CreateNode() : `stn->parent = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));` makes no sense. should probably just be : `stn->parent = NULL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GeoMad89 said, you malloc already existing nodes in the createNode() method.
If you change your createNode() code into this:

```
Node* createNode(Node* parent, Node* suffixNode){

Node *stn = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
stn->id = node_id++;
stn->parent = parent;   //(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
if(suffixNode != NULL)
    stn->suffix_node = suffixNode;  //(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
stn->first_char_index = -1;
stn->last_char_index = -1;
stn->children_size = NODE_BASE_DEGREE;
stn->children_count = 0;
stn->children = (Node**)malloc(stn->children_size*sizeof(Node*));
if(parent != NULL){
    parent->children[parent->children_count++] = stn;
    parent->is_leaf = false;
}
stn->is_leaf = true;
stn->depth = 1;
return stn;
}
```

And if you try it with valgrind, using this toy main:

```
main(int argc, char** argv){

Node* root = createNode(NULL, NULL);
Node* node1 = createNode(root, NULL);
Node* node2 = createNode(root, NULL);
Node* node3 = createNode(node1, NULL);

deleteSubTree(root);

return 0;
}
```

You will see that all the malloc'd memory will be freed!

Needless to say, this code works only with NODE_BASE_DEGREE=2, otherwise, if you use a greater NODE_BASE_DEGREE value, you have to realloc the children array.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the leaf nodes have their children array not empty, because children_size is equal to NODE_BASE_DEGREE.
Try to delete the elements of the array in the leaves before eliminating them.

Comment: NODE_BASE_DEGREE is set to 2 by #include. Children are reallocated inside makeTreeWithUkkonen so they are not of the same size. As you can see leaves' children are freed in the distructor I've made.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed two possible memory leaks:

1. In createNode, i suppose that the parent of the node that you going to create already exist, there is no need to malloc a space for it. But anyway you change the value of the pointer of parent in createSuffixTree, at least in the root of the tree, so this memory that you have allocated in createNode for parent is lost.
2. I don't know what suffix_node is, if is a node of the tree there is the same problem of the point one. But if is another node and so it is correct allocate memory, you don't freed when deleted the tree.